# Matching between char sequences - first occurence before

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like:

```
"This is AA and this is AA and this is AA and this is the END blah blah"
```

I want to match:

```
"AA and this is the END"
```

ie, ending in END, back to the first occurance of AA before END. (Language is Java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
AA(?:(?!AA).)*END
```

A demo:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "This is AA and this is AA and this is AA and this is the END blah blah";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("AA(?:(?!AA).)*END").matcher(text);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println("match ->"+m.group()+"<-");
        }
    }
}
```

And if there can be line breaks between the `AA` and `END`, add a `(?s)` (DOT-ALL flag) at the start of your regex.

A short explanation:

```
AA          # match 'AA'
(?:         # open non-capturing group 1
  (?!AA).   #   if 'AA' cannot be seen, match any char (except line breaks)
)*          # close non-capturing group 1 and repeat it zero or more times
END         # match 'END'
```

Comment: You're welcome Richard. Yes, I know a few regex tricks, but there are quite a few around here who know much more!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer:

```
str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("END")).lastIndexOf("AA");
```

This creates the substring extending to "END" and finds the last occurrence of your search string within that substring.